# Duda con tabla pivote en access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Tengo este query en access, pero no puedo ordenar la Format([FechaCobro],"mmmm") por el orden de los meses, se ordenan por orden alfabético (abril,agosto,diciembre,etc.) y lo quiero por orden de los meses (enero,febrero, etc.)
Este es mi consulta

```
TRANSFORM Sum(Compras.Importe) AS SumaDeImporte
SELECT Compras.PG
FROM Compras
WHERE (((Compras.BU)='EPMV'))
GROUP BY Compras.PG
PIVOT Format([FechaCobro],"mmmm");
```

Gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Format([FechaCobro],"mmmm")` devuelve una cadena, es por ello que aparecen ordenados en orden alfabético. Para ordernar de acuerdo a la secuencia, deberás usar el número en lugar del nombre que corresponde a cada mes.

> NOTA: Asegurate de limitar el reporte a los datos de un sólo año o bien incluir año y mes, en lugar de sólo el mes.

Una forma de abordar casos como este, es producir el resultado deseado por partes, una para realizar los cálculos y obtener la estructura desea, en este caso una tabla pivote, y otra para reemplazar los valores numéricos de los meses por su nombre.